# praogramatically fetch any particular object's related objects from its related list

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am pretty new to SFDC. I am trying to implement a clone functionality of a custom object by which when I am cloning an object, the object as well as all the object in its related list are to be cloned. I have implemented the part of cloning a object but stuck how to get the object list associated with a object's related list. pls let me know , how to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

public class PurchaseOrderCloneWithItemsController {

```
//added an instance varaible for the standard controller
private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
 // add the instance for the variables being passed by id on the url
private Purchase_Order__c po {get;set;}
// set the id of the record that is created -- ONLY USED BY THE TEST CLASS
public ID newRecordId {get;set;}

// initialize the controller
public PurchaseOrderCloneWithItemsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    //initialize the stanrdard controller
    this.controller = controller;
    // load the current record
    po = (Purchase_Order__c)controller.getRecord();

}

// method called from the VF's action attribute to clone the po
public PageReference cloneWithItems() {

     // setup the save point for rollback
     Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
     Purchase_Order__c newPO;

     try {

          //copy the purchase order - ONLY INCLUDE THE FIELDS YOU WANT TO CLONE
         po = [select Id, Name, Ship_To__c, PO_Number__c, Supplier__c, Supplier_Contact__c, Date_Needed__c, Status__c, Type_of_Purchase__c, Terms__c, Shipping__c, Discount__c from Purchase_Order__c where id = :po.id];
         newPO = po.clone(false);
         insert newPO;

         // set the id of the new po created for testing
           newRecordId = newPO.id;

         // copy over the line items - ONLY INCLUDE THE FIELDS YOU WANT TO CLONE
         List<Purchased_Item__c> items = new List<Purchased_Item__c>();
         for (Purchased_Item__c pi : [Select p.Id, p.Unit_Price__c, p.Quantity__c, p.Memo__c, p.Description__c From Purchased_Item__c p where Purchase_Order__c = :po.id]) {
              Purchased_Item__c newPI = pi.clone(false);
              newPI.Purchase_Order__c = newPO.id;
              items.add(newPI);
         }
         insert items;

     } catch (Exception e){
         // roll everything back in case of error
        Database.rollback(sp);
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
     }

    return new PageReference('/'+newPO.id+'/e?retURL=%2F'+newPO.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to "Deep Clone" - check out the links below for reference:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_List_deepClone.htm